# How to fix: docker-compose.yml invalid, unsupport config & invalid type errors

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos, yaml

I'm trying to deploy mattermost locally using docker on a Centos 8 server.  I'm using this guide and tailoring for my distro - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mattermost#With_Docker

I've downloaded docker, and docker compose using the following guide, again tailoring it to Centos - https://docs.mattermost.com/install/prod-docker.html

However it fails on: `docker-compose build`

I used a couple of online checkers for the YAML files, and they're coming back as fine.  Originally I had some indenting errors that I fixed.  I've modified the version fields from 1, 2, 3.2 with no success.

Not sure what else to modify.  I am running this in VMWare Workstation, not sure if that matters.

Current error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.app: 'args'
services.app.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string, or an object
```

compose file :

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    build: db
    read_only: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db/var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=mmuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mmuser_pwd
      - POSTGRES_DB=mattermost
    # uncomment the following to enable backup
    #  - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX
    #  - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX
    #  - WALE_S3_PREFIX=s3://BUCKET_NAME/PATH
    #  - AWS_REGION=us-east-1

  app:
    build:
    context: app
      # uncomment following lines for team edition or change UID/GID
    args:
      - edition=team
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8065:8000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/config:/mattermost/config:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/data:/mattermost/data:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/logs:/mattermost/logs:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/plugins:/mattermost/plugins:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/client-plugins:/mattermost/client/plugins:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      # When you want to use SSO with GitLab, you have to add the cert pki chain of GitLab inside Alpine
      # to avoid Token request failed: certificate signed by unknown authority (link: https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server/issues/13059)
      # - <path_to_your_gitlab_pki>/pki_chain.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/pki_chain.pem:ro
    environment:
      # set same as db credentials and dbname
      - MM_USERNAME=mmuser
      - MM_PASSWORD=mmuser_pwd
      - MM_DBNAME=mattermost

      # use the credentials you've set above, in the format:
      # MM_SQLSETTINGS_DATASOURCE=postgres://${MM_USERNAME}:${MM_PASSWORD}@db:5432/${MM_DBNAME}?sslmode=disable&connect_timeout=10
      - MM_SQLSETTINGS_DATASOURCE=postgres://mmuser:mmuser_password@db:5432/mattermost?sslmode=disable&connect_timeout=10

      # in case your config is not in default location
      #- MM_CONFIG=/mattermost/config/config.json

  web:
    build: web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    read_only: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      # This directory must have cert files if you want to enable SSL
      - ./volumes/web/cert:/cert:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Comment: `context:` and `args:` need to be indented one step more: they are options to `build:`.

Comment: I will attempt this and report.  What about ports thru environment though?

Comment: It worked, thank you.  Now I've got to figure out how to swap out apk for yum commands.

I wonder why none of the online checkers caught that.